# tryCatch:Error not caught

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

Please excuse if the question sounds naive.
While trying to `closeAllConnections()` in a `tryCatch()` block after trying to open file connections recursively, it seems like the error is not caught properly.

Here is the sample code:

```
fileOpenRec<-function(iter){
      if(iter<130){
       try(
        {
         aFile="file1.txt"
         fileCon<-file(aFile, "a")
         fileOpenRec(iter+1)
        }
       )
     }
    }

tryCatch(fileOpenRec(1), error=function(e){print("Error!");closeAllConnections()})
```

The above code throws: `Error in file(aFile, "a") : all connections are in use` and doesn't close the connections.
Is it the expected behaviour? (I doubt that, please correct me if I'm missing something here)

PS: to close the connections I have few work arounds like adding a `finally` and close them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare

```
> tryCatch({ stop("oops"); 1 }, error=function(err) "caught")
[1] "caught"
```

with

```
> tryCatch({ try(stop("oops")); 1 }, error=function(err) "caught")
Error in try(stop("oops")) : oops
[1] 1
```

The inner `try()` catches (and prints) the error, so the outer `tryCatch` has nothing to do. Remove the `try()` from your code.

Comment: Thanks Martin for pointing out the silliness there. I should have seen that.